# Count number of filled out columns in R dataframe to create new column

Tags: r, count

I have a dataframe `df_team` which has multiple Team-Columns, of which of course not all have values. The df looks like this, just with over 100 of these Team_ columns:

```
dput(df_team)

structure(list(Project = c("etwbv", "werg", "sdfg", "qwreg", 
"cae", "refdc"), Team_1 = c("ewrg", "werg", "asd", "qwe", NA, 
"vsfd"), Team_URL_1 = c("abc", "bfh", "fse", "rege", NA, "vsefr"
), Team_2 = c("abc1", "bfh", "fse", "rege1", NA, NA), Team_URL_2 = c("abc", 
"bfh", "fse", "rege", NA, NA), Team_3 = c("abc1", "bfh", NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Team_URL_3 = c("abc", "bfh", NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to create a new column `Team_Count` which counts the filled `Team_x` columns and disregards the NAs, so that I know how many team members one ````Project``` has.

The new dataframe should look like this:

```
Name   Team_1  Team_URL_1 Team_2  Team_URL_2  Team_3  Team_URL_3 Team_Count
etwbv  ewrg    abc        abc1    abc         abc1    abc        3
werg   werg    bfh        bfh     bfh         bfh     bfh        3
sdfg   asd     fse        fse     fse         NA      NA         2
qwreg  qwe     rege       rege1   rege        NA      NA         2
cae    NA      NA         NA      NA          NA      NA         0
refdc  vsfd    vsefr      NA      NA          NA      NA         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Team_Count = rowSums(!is.na(pick(matches("Team_\\d+")))))
```

If you are using dplyr < 1.1.0 then replace `pick` with `across`.

This works by creating a data frame with variables that match the regular expression "Team_\\d+" ("Team_" followed by one or more digits), creating logical values by testing if values are `NA`, and then summing the number of columns that are not `NA` by row.

**Output**

```
  Project Team_1 Team_URL_1 Team_2 Team_URL_2 Team_3 Team_URL_3 Team_Count
1   etwbv   ewrg        abc   abc1        abc   abc1        abc          3
2    werg   werg        bfh    bfh        bfh    bfh        bfh          3
3    sdfg    asd        fse    fse        fse   <NA>       <NA>          2
4   qwreg    qwe       rege  rege1       rege   <NA>       <NA>          2
5     cae   <NA>       <NA>   <NA>       <NA>   <NA>       <NA>          0
6   refdc   vsfd      vsefr   <NA>       <NA>   <NA>       <NA>          1
```